# MacBook Pro randomly shutting down

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, user-account

I have the latest MacBook Pro and am finding that it is randomly shutting down when switching users. This does not happen every time but has happened 7-10 times since I bought it. Should I get it checked out or is this a common bug in Lion?

Comment: I've added an answer [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/204414/unexpected-shut-downs) that offers general guidance.

Answer (score 1):

There was a firmware update for the MBP that addressed unexpected shutdowns...might try that and see if it solve the problem. Look [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1474?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

Answer (score 0):

If this continues after applying all OS and firmware updates, definitely take it into your local Apple Store so they can have a look at it.