# Computer shutting down (dirty) randomly

Tags: macos, shutdown

Everyday when I come back to my system it will be shutoff no matter what I do, if I log out, it'll be shutdown, if I restart it will be shutdown. A grep through the log files shows me this:

```
2018-03-29 16:06:29.964161-0500 0x4a8      Default     0x0                  0      kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 3
2018-03-29 18:30:34.297536-0500 0x435      Default     0x0                  0      kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 3
2018-03-30 09:42:33.355573-0500 0x420      Default     0x0                  0      kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: 3
```

The `3` means hard reboot (or so I've gathered) but I'm not rebooting my system. Is there a way for me to tell what is causing my reboots or if there is an application that is crashing that could be causing this?

*EDIT*:

I've figured out that the `3` is a [*dirty* forced shutdown](https://eclecticlight.co/2017/02/28/mac-shutdown-and-sleep-cause-codes/), so this leaves the question, how can I determine what is causing the issue?

Comment: It is recommended to contact Apple authorised service provider and get your Mac diagnosed by a technician. It probably appears to be some kind of hardware issue. If you bought an AppleCare, you may be eligible for free service and repairs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected shut downs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/204414/unexpected-shut-downs)

Comment: @NimeshNeema I'd do that, but I'm the sysadmin, so I like challenges lol.

Comment: As indicated by the log output and the symptoms, it seems to be a hardware problem. Hence the suggestion.

Comment: @NimeshNeema So the `3` does indeed mean that it was hard rebooted? EDIT: Found the codes [here](https://eclecticlight.co/2017/02/28/mac-shutdown-and-sleep-cause-codes/)

Comment: Indeed. Refer to this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/255401/279727

Comment: Close voters:  Not a dupe because the OP has specifically identified the shutdown cause unlike the linked question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually believe I've found a fix for this.

I started `grep`ing through all the log files from when this issue started happening looking for a pattern. As it turns out the pattern is that the `GoogleSoftwareUpdateDaemon` runs *everytime* right before the crash happens:

```
Mar 30 13:33:55 <COMP-NAME> GoogleSoftwareUpdateDaemon[19078]: 2018-03-30 13:33:55.245 GoogleSoftwareUpdateDaemon[19078/0x7fff77030000] [lvl=2] -[KeystoneDaemon main] GoogleSoftwareUpdateDaemon inactive, shutdown.
Mar 30 13:34:00 localhost kernel[0]: Previous shutdown cause: 3
```

So doing some research, this is a updater that is secretly installed by Google (*it is nowhere in their terms of service, nor is there a warning for it*) what this does is update your Google applications *every 5 hours*. In order to disable this you can do the following:

```
defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0
```

What that command will do is set the interval for checking to `0`. This is probably not recommended since security updates are important, so you can also set the interval for once a week:

```
defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 604800
```

Now apparently this updater takes up very minuscule amounts of resources, but what they don't tell you is that it depends on how much Google software is on your system, it runs all the updates at one time. For example, if you have Google Chrome, Google Drive, and Google Hangouts installed, it will attempt to run updates for all of those pieces of software at once.

So what I did is the first option, set it to `0` and watched the computer for over an hour. Nothing happened, restarted and it boot right up, watched for another hour and it didn't crash or turn off. Going to assume this was the problem and move on with my life.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to share your findings on this. I'm sure it'll be helpful to other users! :) Since this is a highly unusual way for a hard shutdown to occur (I don't recall ever seeing a software cause for this particular type of shutdown), can I encourage you to send a bug report to Google about this? Here's [how to](https://www.google.com/tools/feedback/intl/en/learnmore.html). Finally, welcome to Ask Different! I hope you find this site a valuable resource! :)

Comment: @Monomeeth I've already been in contact with them, I've also asked them to provide where in the ToS it says a daemon is installed. Still waiting, will provide a link once I've gotten an answer.

Comment: @CertifcateJunky Where did you find these logs and how exactly did you search through them?

Comment: @Ska it's in your syslog

Comment: @CertifcateJunky You mean /var/log folder and all the files there, or?

Comment: @Ska `/var/log/system.log` should be in there, run `cat /var/log/system.log | grep -i "googleupdate"` if it's on your system you should find it that way.

Comment: @Ska hey, if you where not able to find it in the syslog, try the following:
`for f in $(ls /var/log); do cat /var/log/$f | grep -i "googleupdate"; echo -e "FILENAME: $F\n"; done`. That will cat all the available file in your `/var/log` directory for anything relating to `GoogleUpdate`

Comment: My computer kept shutting down 1-10 minutes after startup. I have just ran this command, and my computer still hasn't shut down after ~1 hour. I am floored that this was (perhaps, I may comment again if it wasn't) the cause, congratulations for the find!

Answer (score 4):

A shutdown cause of "3" is a hard shutdown - when you press and hold the power button.

More than likely there's a contaminant causing a short that is forcing the button to engage (electrically speaking) thus making your Mac "see" an ACPI shutdown.

Try cleaning it but you may have to have it replaced.